# How to deal with duplicate insertion in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have an ADF pipeline to copy data from ADLS to Data Explorer(ADX).
I am reading all the data and able to copy to ADX.
[image]
Problem is that every time my pipeline runs and ingest data the ADX table gets duplicate data in table.

The source folder containing log files which are logs of a copy activity triggered every two hours with new files. And the logs contains new copied file details.

So, how do I fix the issue of duplication, is there a way to upsert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nikolai suggested in his third point-
Clear the destination table prior to export where you delete all records from the table and then export your latest batch. This is not really a great option but could be a quick and dirty solution if your source stores all the data that you need.

And since it is a quick fix for me, I used same and achieved using below.

I have used a `Azure Data Explorer Command` activity for this followed by a `Copy` Activity. It works like a charm.
We can run definition query as well as control queries using `ADX Command` activity.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that the issue is with the fact you're ingesting the same data more than once (i.e., duplicates are expected), and you're not having unexpected duplicates.

one trivial solution would be avoiding ingesting the same data more than once.

other approaches for handling duplicate data are documented here: [Handle duplicate data in Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates).

Comment: the source folder containing log files which are logs of a copy activity triggered every two hours with new files. And the logs contains new copied file details.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible methods of dealing with this. Often times the best method depends on your use-case. Let's define some terms with *Source* being your ADF source and *Destination Table* being your final table in ADX.

- *Materialized View* where your destination table continues to contain duplicates. The *materialized view* uses an `arg_max` function over the export timestamp/ingestion time to only show the latest export.
- *Staging table* where you export the data into a staging table. From there you have a copy function that moves the data into your destination table. The copy function can be customized with logic that defines the concept of duplicate records. It could be as simple as an anti-join against your destination table on all records. Your destination table will contain unique values only and the staging table can be configured to have a very short retention time.
- *Clear the destination table prior to export* where you delete all records from the table and then export your latest batch. This is not really a great option, but could be a quick and dirty solution if your source stores all the data that you need.

Comment: The third option of deleting before ingestion looks good for now since it is a quick fix.
 Just wondering if I can use this clear event from ADF or from ADX I have to use KQL for this.

Comment: You can use Azure Data Factory to run an Azure Data Explorer Command to drop the rows (for example `.drop extents from TableName`). Then on success you can kick off the Copy job.

Comment: I added a lookup before copy and in Query I tried this "['log-table'] .clear table ['log-table'] data" and getting error message: Read from Kusto failed with following error= Syntax error: Expected: ;. Query: .

Comment: Use a "Azure Data Explorer Command" block in Azure Data Factory. A Syntax error generally means there is an issue with your query itself. I would recommend running the query in the web UI first to make sure that it works. The command as you have written it would not work, see the sample here: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/clear-table-data-command